# Prevent PDF from auto-downloading and have it Auto Print instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf

I have a situation where when a user is viewing their order history, they are provided a link to *print* a PDF version of their invoice. Currently when the user clicks on the link the PDF will automatically download to their computer.

The 'higher-ups' are wanting that to be changed, so when the user clicks the link to print the pdf, a print dialogue box will appear instead of automatically downloading the PDF.

I've been able to get the pdf open in a new window but when ever the pdf is being called it won't display the pdf but will automatically download it instead.

I've searched all over the internet and SO for a solution but have yet to yield any results. This needs to be done, if possible, via JavaScript or jQuery.

**HTML**

```
<p><a id="print_pdf" target="_blank">Click to Print Invoice</a>
```

**JavaScript / jQuery**

```
var print_pdf_link = $('#print_pdf').attr('href');
var linkNo2 = "privatefile.dhtml~useridtext~&file=~username~_rep.pdf";
$('#print_pdf').click(function(){
  w = window.open(linkNo2);
  w.print();
});
```

I've also used:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('privatefile.dhtml~useridtext~&file=~username~_rep.pdf', '_blank', 'fullscreen=yes'); return fal
se;">MyPDF</a>
```

* *please note the text between tilde are placeholders that contain values from the back-end*

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sounds like you should build a print-only stylesheet instead. You can then wire the button to `window.print()` to print the page without downloading anything.

Comment: I believe that browser's preferences will take precedence in many cases so any solutions you might find will not be bullet proof if you do not hvae control over the user's browser settings (i.e. outside corporate standard built PCs)

Comment: @Blazemonger, How would I have that apply to a .pdf that's generated via backend [perl]?

Comment: @ochi That's certainly something to keep in mind, I have thought about that but I think it might be something to bring up to the 'higher-ups'

Comment: Do you generate those PDFs from HTML? Do you have a version of invoices in HTML, so you can print that instead?

Comment: I think your best course of action is to gather arguments to convince the higher-ups why you will not implement that feature. I, as a user, do not want automatic printing. I want to save the PDF to my Dropbox and print it at home at my own convenience. Or not even print on paper at all, because that is environmental waste. I am sorry that this is not a technical answer, but sometimes the best solution is to decide that it isn't a problem worth solving. This is one of them.

Comment: It is nice to offer PDF to download and print besides it, Amedee. The problem is that browsers are not PDF viewers, so he can print only HTML page (code or image).

Comment: @skobaljic, the PDF's are generated from the backend.

Comment: Same backend could generate HTML page for printing, I would go that way (open the page later and do javascript `window.print()` on page load). One more solution is to use some [pdf-to-image library](https://github.com/spatie/pdf-to-image) and open the image in new window (also with javascript print).

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse, The backend programmer eventually had a conversation with the 'higher-ups' (along with my notes and comments on this project) and it was determined that we will just change the text on the page instead of trying to intercept the auto-downloaded pdf.

Comment: And there was much rejoicing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it i hope i would make use of.

```js
var pfHeaderImgUrl = '';
var pfHeaderTagline = '';
var pfdisableClickToDel = 0;
var pfHideImages = 0;
var pfImageDisplayStyle = 'right';
var pfDisablePDF = 0;
var pfDisableEmail = 0;
var pfDisablePrint = 0;
var pfCustomCSS = '';
var pfBtVersion = '1';

(function() {
  var js, pf;
  pf = document.createElement('script');
  pf.type = 'text/javascript';

  if ('https:' === document.location.protocol) {
    js = 'http://domain.com//main.js'
  } else {
    js = 'http://domain.com/printfriendly.js'
  }
  pf.src = js;
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(pf)
})();
```

```html
<a href="" 
   style="color:#6D9F00;text-decoration:none;"
   class="printfriendly" 
   onclick="window.print();return false;"
   title="Print">Print</a>
```

Comment: I am reading this on the Android app. Could you *please* not put everything on one line?

Comment: @waqt, I added in your code but it only seemed to print the .html page. It didn't stop the PDF from auto-downloading and, instead, provide a print dialogue box for the .pdf.

Comment: You mean you already have some pdf's for users and want to direct display for users, when they click on downloading or displaying link?

Comment: Mr.Amedee Van Gasse, i put it on line but, ochi has edited everything, Please request him to do that

Comment: @waqt, when the user clicks on the PDF link, the backend will create the PDF and automatically download it to the users's computer. I'm needing to somehow intercept or stop, the automatic download, and have a print dialogue box appear instead. Thus having the PDF print instead of download/save

Comment: @JHWebDev, Above code is 100% ok, it si browser fault that you are telling, Please upgrade your browser by downloading tool from here https://www.pdfill.com/ , ie 6 is not able to do everything what you want? Amedee Van Gasse has already told you about this.

Comment: @waqt, the code does work but it captured the .html page, not the pdf download, that is activated via separate link and created and automatically downloaded via the backend [perl] code.  The browser I'm using (chrome) is also fully up-to-date.